# Как добавлять и удалять Widgets?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qlabel, qcheckbox

Я хочу добавлять и удалять `widgets`, но я не знаю как мне это сделать.

Я набросал вот такой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, id='0', parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText('label-{}'.format(id))


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.CheckBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.CheckBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.CheckBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        
        self.CheckBox_1.setText('CheckBox_1')
        self.CheckBox_2.setText('CheckBox_2')
        self.CheckBox_3.setText('CheckBox_3')
        
        self.CheckBox_1.clicked.connect(self.addLabel)
        self.CheckBox_2.clicked.connect(self.addLabel)
        self.CheckBox_3.clicked.connect(self.addLabel)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_2)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_3)
        
    def addLabel(self):
        if self.sender().isChecked() :
            self.label = Label(self.sender().text())
            self.lay.addWidget(self.label)
        else:
            self.lay.removeWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я знаю что вопрос банален, но я не совсем понимаю что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, id='0', parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
#        self.label.setText('label-{}'.format(id))
        self.setText('label-{}'.format(id))


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
       
        self.CheckBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.CheckBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.CheckBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        
        self.CheckBox_1.setText('CheckBox_1')
        self.label_1 = Label('CheckBox_1')
        self.CheckBox_2.setText('CheckBox_2')
        self.label_2 = Label('CheckBox_2')
        self.CheckBox_3.setText('CheckBox_3')
        self.label_3 = Label('CheckBox_3')
        
        self.CheckBox_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addLabel(self.CheckBox_1, self.label_1))
        self.CheckBox_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addLabel(self.CheckBox_2, self.label_2))
        self.CheckBox_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addLabel(self.CheckBox_3, self.label_3))

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_2)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.CheckBox_3)
        self.lay.addStretch(1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lay.addStretch(1)
        self.label_1.hide()
        self.label_2.hide()
        self.label_3.hide()
        
    def addLabel(self, cb, lb):
        if cb.isChecked() :
            lb.show()
        else:
            lb.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]